# Conditions of invertibility, linear transformations

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Please, I need a hint. :)
Let   $T:\Bbb R^m\rightarrow \Bbb R^n$  and $ U:\Bbb R^n \rightarrow \Bbb R^m $ be linear transformations. What are the conditions that $m, n$ have to satisfy to $UT:\Bbb R^m \rightarrow \Bbb R^m$ be a invertible linear transformation?

Comment: I think you have a typo. $UT$goes to $\mathbb{R}^m$, not $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: Do you mean a necessary condition? (I think a sufficient condition is not possible if $T$ and $U$ can be arbitrary linear transformations.)

Answer (score 0):

It seems the following.

$UT$ is an invertible linear transformation iff both $U$ and $T$ are injections, that is
$$\dim\text{ran } U=\dim\text{ran } T=\text{rank } U=\text{rank } T=m$$

(in particular, necessarily, $n\ge m$).